# How to get DOS for each iteration?

Tags: density-functional-theory

Do any Density Functional Theory (DFT) codes (for example, QE ABINIT, Fleur, ....) provide the availability of getting the density of states (DOS) which produced by each iteration of the Self-Consistent Loop? If no, so, how can I get them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are DFT and DOS?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my question.